# $compile(html)(scope) ignores the scope I've created manually

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Here is my code :

HTML:

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">    {{model.name}}   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

var $injector =angular.injector(['ng']); 
$injector.invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var html = '<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">{{model.name}}</div>'

    var scope = $rootScope.$new();

    scope.model = {name:'MyCtrl1'};
    //alert(scope.model.name);
    var e3 = $compile(html)(scope);

    $('#container').append(e3[0]);
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.model={};
    $scope.model.name = 'MyCtrl';

};
function MyCtrl1($scope) {   
    //alert('MyCtrl1');
};
```

[Here is a fiddle showing the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/alehro/Bfwgg/2/)

As you can see it renders two 'MyCtrl' strings. I.e. angular ignores the scope object I've created manually.

The question is: How do I make `$compile` to use the scope I've created?

---

UPDATE: Ugly workaround:

After a call to `$compile` apply model one more time:

```
angular.element(e3[0]).scope().$apply(function(scope) {
    scope.model = {name:'MyCtrl1'};
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ng-app creates an injector, then you are creating another one.  This is probably not what you want.  I moved most of your code into a [run()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#run) method, which has the $compile service and $rootScope injected into it:

```
app.run(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var html = '<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">{{model.name}}</div>'

    var scope = $rootScope.$new();

    scope.model = {name:'MyCtrl1'};
    //alert(scope.model.name);
    var e3 = $compile(html)(scope);
    scope.$apply();

    $('#container').append(e3[0]);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Fyhau/)

`scope.$apply()` is needed, but I'm not sure why.  Hopefully someone else can explain that to us.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that $injector is app singleton. That explains my troubles. I cannot use your solution literally because I'm in legacy code and all I have there is 'angular' variable. But I think I could get one of controllers and call the code in its context.  Anyway thank you for explanation, I will test it on next occasion.

Comment: Angular isn't really creating a new scope, unless it seems you call `$apply()`.  Really new elements should be created in directives, I'm guessing when angular bootstraps it just over-writes the bindings and scope you create initially...